# Find a formula for $\langle X_n\rangle$ which is defined recursively as follows

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$X_1=a$, $X_2=b$ and $X_{n+2}=(X_n+X_{n+1})/2$

Find a formula for $\langle X_n\rangle$ valid for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

I wrote a few terms in this sequence and tried to derive a formula. But I couldn't come up with a solution. Any hints on how to solve this?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the characteristic equation:

$$q^2 = \frac{q}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$$

$$q = 1,-\frac{1}{2}$$

Using these two roots:
$$X_n = c_1 + c_2(-\frac{1}{2})^n$$

$$X_1 = c_1 - \frac{c_2}{2} = a$$
$$X_2 = c_1 + \frac{c_2}{4} = b$$

Solving the system of equations:
$$c_1 = \frac{a + 2b}{3}$$
$$c_2 = \frac{4(b-a)}{3}$$

Giving us the final answer:
$$X_n = \frac{a + 2b}{3} + \left(\frac{4(b-a)}{3}\right)(\frac{-1}{2})^n$$